# Report Builder 3.0 always consider Month perameter as default perameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, reportbuilder3.0

I have the reports with Month as Input parameter also had the other parameters. When I open the Reports getting the data for data default month October.
I have data for November month also. So in reports when I change the month to November as report parameter then view the report getting the report data for November month successfully.

But when I Open the report in Report Builder It is pulling the report data for default month October. Though I have changed the Month parameter to November and view the report in Report Builder it always getting October month data.

Please advice.

Comment: Hi maybe you put October like default value. In you parameter open propertys and check if you have this month like default value.

Comment: In the Perameter Properties Advanced Options selected Always Refresh Option. Then the Report builder pulling the data for the month what ever i have selected in the Month Perameter.

Comment: But in the Web reports the selected Option is Never Refresh. If selected option is always should be "Always Refresh" then for the web reports also changed the Option and redeploy the report to reflect this "Always Refresh" option in Report Builder?
Please advice

Comment: Hi you execute this from a webform? maybe you forget put ReportViewe1.Refresh()